# PayPal Express Checkout - Create Recurring Payment Profile not working

Tags: php, paypal

We are Using Recurring Payments with the Express Checkout API. We follow the following link
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id086513007E9

1. Recurring payment with Initial amount :-

My request to create recurring payment

```
METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=86&PWD=password&USER=XXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=signature&TOKEN=token&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-11-26T10%3A15%3A48Z&DESC=Silver+-+USD+3.95&BILLINGPERIOD=Day&BILLINGFREQUENCY=4&INITAMT=1&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

The response of request :-

```
Array
(
[PROFILEID] => I-L28955XWTU84
[PROFILESTATUS] => PendingProfile
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-26T10:15:54Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 83fa402749c8c
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 86
[BUILD] => 13630372
)
```

In response PROFILESTATUS is "PendingProfile" but it supposed to "ActiveProfile" and in customer account no amount deducted.

2. Without initial amount recurring

   METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=86&PWD=password&USER=XXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=signature&TOKEN=token&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-11-26T10%3A26%3A13Z&DESC=Silver+-+USD+3.95&BILLINGPERIOD=Day&BILLINGFREQUENCY=4&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard

The response of request :-

```
Array
(
[PROFILEID] => I-1RXFKHJ5H846
[PROFILESTATUS] => ActiveProfile
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-26T10:26:21Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 6f793b6e64a35
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 86
[BUILD] => 13630372
)
```

When I am doing recurring without initial amount it returns "ActiveProfile".

I want to do recurring with initial amount and expecting an active profile with instant initial amount deduction from the customer account, so please help me to fix this problem. Please note - pwd/signature/token is masked, in actual code we have put the real pwd/signature/token.

Thanks.

Comment: we have existing issue on this in Sandbox.The issue is not resolved as yet.

Comment: @Vimal :- so for clarification, if I will do payment from PayPal live account then this issue will not come ?

Answer (score 0):

remove String INITAMT=1    ------> ActiveProfile